# Difference in using Visiblity and Style of a div tag

Tags: asp.net, html

What is the difference below?

```
<div id="div1" runat="server" visible="false">Hello</div>
```

In contrast, I can do this

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with the first, the div will not be rendered to page.

with the second (display:none;), it will be rendered to the page, but not visible.

You can see this by viewing the source of the rendered page for each example.

Comment: So which method will you suggest to use? or does it depend upon your requirements...?

Comment: it depends, if you are going to use javascript to show the div based on a user action (clicking a 'show more' link) then use display:none;.  If you don't want to show the div at all, based on some logic, then set visibility to false.  Since visibility=false will not render the div at all, javascript would not be able to access it.